# android +php+ mysql

Tags: php, android, mysql, error-handling

I am creating a mobile application that have access to an external database to retrieve some data but the problem is in the logcat I got error can anyone help me I will appreciate that

## TestExternalDatabaseActivity.java

```
package com.taseen.apps;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.R.array;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TestExternalDatabaseActivity extends Activity {

    TextView resultView;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.testexternaldatabase);

    resultView =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.result);
    getData();



    }


   public void getData() 
   {
       String  result = "";
       InputStream isr = null;

       try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
           HttpPost httppost = new  HttpPost("127.0.0.2/getAllCustomers.php");
           HttpResponse response  = httpclient.execute(httppost);
           HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
           try {
            isr = entity.getContent();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e4) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e4.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.e("log-tag", "Error in  connection"+e.toString());
        resultView.setText("could not connect to database");


        //convert response to string 

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new  BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(isr, "iso-8859-1"),8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while((line = reader.readLine())!= null)
            {
                sb.append(line + "\n");

            }
            isr.close();

            result = sb.toString();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.e("Log-tag", "Error converting  result" +e.toString());




    //parse json data

            try {
                String s ="";
                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

                for(int i = 0; i<jArray.length(); i++)
                {
                    JSONObject json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    s =  s +
                            "Name: "+json.getString("FirstName")+" "+json.getString("LastName")+"\n"+
                            "Age: "+json.getString("Age")+"\n"+
                            "Mobile Used: "+json.getString("Mobile")+"\n\n";

                }

                resultView.setText(s);
            } catch (JSONException e2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Log.e("log-tag", "Error parsing data"+e.toString());
            }


    } catch (IOException e3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e3.printStackTrace();
        }





   } catch (IOException e5) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e5.printStackTrace();
    }

  }
}
```

## the logcat:

```
04-02 19:12:24.933: D/AndroidRuntime(331): Shutting down VM
04-02 19:12:24.933: W/dalvikvm(331): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
04-02 19:12:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(331): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-02 19:12:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(331): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.taseen.apps/com.taseen.apps.TestExternalDatabaseActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Target host must not be null, or set in parameters.
04-02 19:12:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
04-02 19:12:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
04-02 19:12:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
04-02 19:12:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
04-02 19:12:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-02 19:12:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-02 19:12:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
04-02 19:12:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-02 19:12:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-02 19:12:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
04-02 19:12:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
04-02 19:12:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-02 19:12:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(331): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Target host must not be null, or set in parameters.
04-02 19:12:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.determineRoute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:572)
04-02 19:12:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:292)
04-02 19:12:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
04-02 19:12:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
04-02 19:12:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
04-02 19:12:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at com.taseen.apps.TestExternalDatabaseActivity.getData(TestExternalDatabaseActivity.java:51)
04-02 19:12:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at com.taseen.apps.TestExternalDatabaseActivity.onCreate(TestExternalDatabaseActivity.java:36)
04-02 19:12:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-02 19:12:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
04-02 19:12:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  ... 11 more
```

## getAllCustomers.php

```
<?php

$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root")or die(mysql_error());

mysql_select_db("TestDatabase", $con) or die("can not connect to the database");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM customer")or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $output[] = $row;
}
  print(json_encode($output));

  mysql_close();

?>
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: The error log says that the target host isn't set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is that you forgot the `http://` prefix try this code:

```
HttpPost httppost = new  HttpPost("http://192.168.0.1/getAllCustomers.php");
```

Note that you also need to set the actual server ip instad of localhost.

Comment: @ rekire i  am using the localhost  so i need to run this on the localhost

Comment: this was the error the http:    now the application run  but i do not get anything  just the "textView"

Comment: If I guess right than the string is inside your variable `result`, you need to set it to your TextView with a code like this: `((TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_view_1)).setText(result);`

Answer (score 0):

The error tells you the problem...

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Target host must not be null, or set in parameters.

Are you sure you mean to use `127.0.0.2`? Do you have a PHP server running at that IP Address?